# Error: Cannot call React.createContext because property createContext is missing in object type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types, flowtype

I am attempting to use the new React Context API in my application. My application is also using `flow` for types. As soon as I add `// @flow` to the top of a file that contains the code:

```
const MyContext = React.createContext()
```

I receive an error telling me:

```
Cannot call React.createContext because property createContext is missing in object type [1].
```

Where `object type [1]` is referring to a [union type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/) export from a flow types file for react, that contains types for `DOM`, `PropTypes`, `version`, `createClass`, etc. I imagine the best way to handle this would be to type `MyContext` to be something like:

```
const MyContext: Context = React.createContext()
```

But for the life of me I cannot find any such information on doing this. There seems to be no type definition for `Context`, or the return value of `React.createContext`. Has anyone ran into this issue, or know how to fix?

Comment: You should upgrade to latest flow version

Comment: that seems to have resolved the issue, thanks Aleksey!

Comment: Yeah, `createContext` typings were added in `0.70.0`

Answer (score 2):

React.createContext expects a type for the argument being passed to it. In your case, the type is null:
`const MyContext = React.createContext<null>()`

Here is another example with an argument `'test'` of type string:
`const MyContext = React.createContext<string>('test')`

Answer (score 1):

Updating `flow-bin` from `0.68.0` to `0.72.0` seems to have done the trick.